# How to trace through basic recursive code in java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to recursion and don't understand how it works.

This was a classwork problem that had the answer 18, but I don't understand how. From what I know, this should return 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 (3 + m-1 on the recursive line)?

Are the subtraction signs not indicative of subtraction?  (assuming that m = 5)

```
public int test(int m)
{
   int value;
   if (m == 0)
      value = 3;
   else
      value = test(m - 1) + 3;
   return value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 (3 + m-1 on the recursive line)? Are the subtraction
> signs not indicative of subtraction?

No the `+3` will happen for every one of the recursive calls, actually what your function is doing is given the value of (m times 3) + 3.

So for `m=5` the recursive calls will be like:

Is m = 0 ? No so let us called recursively:

1. test(4) + 3
2. m = 4; then test(3) + 3 + 3
3. m = 3; then test(2) + 3 + 3 + 3
4. m = 2; then test(1) + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
5. m = 1; then test(0) + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
6. m = 0; then exit with 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3

Hence, for `m=5` you get `18`.

A side-note you can use the [ternary operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-ternary-operator-with-examples/) to simplify your method to:

```
static public int test(int m) {
    return (m == 0) ? 3 : test(m - 1) + 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For visualizing what happens, scatter the code with messages:

```
public int test(int m)
{
   System.out.println("entering test("+m+")");
   int value;
   if (m == 0)
      value = 3;
   else
      value = test(m - 1) + 3;
   System.out.println("returning "+value+" from test("+m+")");
   return value;
}
```

Of course this is just the minimal program, you could also show which branch of the `if` was taken, `m-1`, and so on.

JavaScript equivalent, so it can run here in the browser:

```js
function test(m) {
  console.log("entering test(" + m + ")");
  var value;
  if (m == 0)
    value = 3;
  else
    value = test(m - 1) + 3;
  console.log("returning " + value + " from test(" + m + ")");
  return value;
}

console.log("result: "+test(3));
```

On the longer run it is a good idea to learn using the debugger of the environment you are using. Among other things, debuggers can step through code line-by-line.